# Join the results of two MapReduce jobs together

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am trying to join the results I get from two MapReduce jobs. The first job returns the 5 most influential papers. Below is the code for the first reducer.

```
import sys
import operator

current_word = None
current_count = 0
word = None
topFive = {}
# input comes from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()

    # parse the input we got from mapper.py
    word, check = line.split('\t')
    if check != None:
        count = 1

    if current_word == word:
        current_count += count
    else:
        if current_word:
            topFive.update({current_word: current_count})
            #print(current_word, current_count)
        current_count = count
        current_word = word
if current_word == word:

    print(current_word, current_count)

t = sorted(topFive.iteritems(), key=lambda x:-x[1])[:6]
print("Top five most cited papers")
count = 1
for x in t:
    if x[0] != 'nan' and count <= 5:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(*x))
        count = count + 1
```

The second job finds the 5 most influential authors and the code is more or less the same as the code above. I want to take the results from these two jobs and join them so that I can determine for each author, the average number of citation of their 3 most influential papers. I cannot figure out how to do this, it seems I need to somehow join the results?

Answer (score 0):

So far you will end up with two output directories, one for the authors and one for the papers.

Now you want to do a JOIN operation (as in the DBs lingo) with both of the files. To do so, the MapReduce way is to make a third job with performs this operation with the two outputs files.

JOIN operations in Hadoop are well studied. One way to do it is the reducer-side join pattern. The pattern consists in the mapper creating a composite key of two subkeys (One the original key + a boolean key specifying whether is table 0 or 1).

Before getting to the reducer you need to make a partitioner that separates those composite keys. The reducers will just get all the same keys from every table.

Let me know if you need further clarification, I wrote this one pretty fast.